# Gravitational force inside a sphere - Where is the mistake?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

There is a sphere, with $\frac{dM}{dV}=\frac{M}{V}=\rho$. I want to calculate the gravitaional force along the z-axis.
$$dF=G\frac{m*dM}{r^2}$$
$$dF=\frac{GmM}{V}*\frac{dxdydz}{r^2}$$
$$dF=\iiint \limits_V \frac{GmM}{V}*\frac{dxdydz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
If $\textbf{v}(x,y,z)=\textbf{v}(0,0,-1)$, then $\textbf{F}=F_{down}\textbf{v}-F_{up}\textbf{v}$
$$dV=r*dz*dr*d\theta$$
$$F_{down}=\int \limits_{-R}^{h} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} c*\frac{r}{z^2+r^2} dr*d\theta*dz$$
$$F_{up}=\int \limits_{h}^{R} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} c*\frac{r}{z^2+r^2} dr*d\theta*dz$$
Where $c=\frac{GmM}{V}$, and $h$ is the (signed) distance from the centre off mass.

And I've god $\textbf{F}=2ch\pi(\log{\frac{R^2}{h^2}}+1)\textbf{v}$

But with $R=1$, $2c\pi=1$, the graph looks like this:[image: image description]

And it looks wrong for me, because i think the max/min should be at $|z|=R$ for $z\in[-R,R]$.

Comment: why are you restricting your integration to positive $z$'s?

Comment: What do you mean, @ZeroTheHero?

Comment: Sorry I misread your setup. I thought your last integral was over $z$'s since it's the last in your differential element.  I don't follow at all your train of thoughts so I'm afraid I can't be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

You are not factoring in the fact that force is a vector. You should have, for example,

$$dF_{z} = \frac{G\,m\,\rho\,dx\,dy\,dz}{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}}\right)$$

Though you will honestly have an easier time of this just using the standard Gauss's law argument here.

Comment: I did, that's why i was integrating from -R to h, and then from h to R.

Comment: I didn't know what to do with vectors in the integral, so i was using scalars, with respect to the direction.

Comment: @user145014 : basically, you have to calculate three scalars, one for each component

Comment: My original integral was this: http://imgur.com/a/ysTyx , but the integral became really hard after evaluating the first one (dx). But maybe this is also wrong.

Comment: @user145014 : Like I said, you're way better off using Gauss's law to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you give any source, where i can learn about it?

Comment: @user145014 : any calculus-based physics textbook will cover it.

Comment: What I've found on the internet is about electrodynamics.

Comment: @user145014: I'd really recommend forgetting about the internet, and going to a used book store, and picking up a calculus-based physics textbook.  Also, electrostatics and electrodynamics are deeply linked.  But there are numerous resources out there:  https://www.khanacademy.org/search?page_search_query=gauss%27s%20law

Comment: I don't get it. How could i use Gauss's Law? Both of the Coulomb's Law and Newton's Law are inverse-square law. But that's the connection only. What could i use the Gauss's Law for? And how?

Comment: @user145014: Coulomb's law is equivalent to Gauss's law, there is therefore, an equivalent "gravitational" Gauss's law, which you can get by simply substituting $Q_{inc} \rightarrow M_{inc}$, ${\vec E} \rightarrow {\vec g}$, and $\epsilon_{0}\rightarrow \frac{1}{4\pi G}$

Comment: Yes, but what could i do with it?

Comment: @user145014: look up the derivation for the field inside of a uniformly charged sphere.

Comment: I've tried the inregral over dV gdA=4πGM, so g=4πG*rho*V/A. I've made again a g_up and g_down, summed them, and got g=-4/3*rho*G*π*(2h³-10hR²)/(9R²-h²), where R is the radius of the sphere, h is rhe distance from the centre of gravity. The dimension is good, the values at h=0 and h=R are good. But is it good?